# Run SQL file from SQLBrowser for Sybase

Tags: sybase, sqlbrowser

I need to execute a .sql file from my local drive in the SQLBrowser client for Sybase.

Can you suggest how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Its on page 30 of the manual found at http://www.sqlbrowser.com/Manual.pdf

There are images showing the menu options so easier to check the manual directly.

Comment: Thanks for your response, this is not what I am looking for. It talks about creating a file or opening a file and executing line by line or select all and execute. What I need is something like we have in SQL Developer @C:\temp\1.sql

Comment: Why not use the default isql client provided from Sybase (or nowadays SAP) for this purpose rather than a GUI tool?